# How to run soapUI tests from Java

Tags: java, soapui

I need to run SoapUI test by Java. Could you please advise me useful links? And I would be happy if you can show me how to load/run tests (code examples).

I also found only one link which can be applicable for my project - http://pritikaur23.wordpress.com/2013/06/16/saving-a-soapui-project-and-sending-requests-using-soapui-api/ .

But when I try to do the same I faced below errors -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/SchemaTypeSystem;
```

It's weird because i added all needed jar files. Also I even tried different versions of a xmlbeans.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the way how to run soapUI test by code.

---

The small explanation:

Firstly - I created a maven project and added dependencies to pom.xml instead of a including .jar directly. For the SoapUI tests was needed to add following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Secondly - I also added a few dependencies because I got an exceptions

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

The needed dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jgoodies</groupId>
        <artifactId>looks</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.squirrel-sql.thirdparty-non-maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>com-fifesoft-rsyntaxtextarea</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.eik.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

After preparing of the environment I was able to write a code. I show you an example of a code what able to run all test suites and test cases in a specified soapUI project by Java.

```
    // method for running all Test Suites and test cases in the project
public static void getTestSuite() throws Exception {

    String suiteName = "";
    String reportStr = "";

    // variables for getting duration
    long startTime = 0;
    long duration = 0;

    TestRunner runner = null;

    List<TestSuite> suiteList = new ArrayList<TestSuite>();
    List<TestCase> caseList = new ArrayList<TestCase>();

    SoapUI.setSoapUICore(new StandaloneSoapUICore(true));

    // specified soapUI project
    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject("your-soapui-project.xml");

    // get a list of all test suites on the project
    suiteList = project.getTestSuiteList();

    // you can use for each loop
    for(int i = 0; i < suiteList.size(); i++){

        // get name of the "i" element in the list of a test suites
        suiteName = suiteList.get(i).getName();
        reportStr = reportStr + "\nTest Suite: " + suiteName;

        // get a list of all test cases on the "i"-test suite
        caseList = suiteList.get(i).getTestCaseList();


        for(int k = 0; k < caseList.size(); k++){

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // run "k"-test case in the "i"-test suite
            runner = project.getTestSuiteByName(suiteName).getTestCaseByName(caseList.get(k).getName()).run(new PropertiesMap(), false);

            duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

            reportStr = reportStr + "\n\tTestCase: " + caseList.get(k).getName() + "\tStatus: " + runner.getStatus() + "\tReason: " + runner.getReason() + "\tDuration: " + duration;
        }

    }

    // string of the results
    System.out.println(reportStr);
}
```

Output:

```
Test Suite: TS_ONE
    TestCase: TC_ONE    Status: FAILED  Reason: Cancelling due to failed test step  Duration: 1549
    TestCase: TC_TWO    Status: FINISHED    Reason: {}  Duration: 1277
    ...
    TestCase: TC_N  Status: FAILED  Reason: Cancelling due to failed test step  Duration: 1282
Test Suite: TS_TWO
    TestCase: TC_BlaBla Status: FINSHED Reason: {}  Duration: 1280
    ...
```

---

I hope the information above will help someone.

Comment: I want to test API by passing the payload at run time which I will be getting from somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Using a continuous integration server (eg Hudson is perfect for this) it is possible to run unit tests automatically JUnit format. Below is an example of integrating SoapUI project in a JUnit test.

```
public void testRunner() throws Exception 
{
    SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner(); 
    runner.setProjectFile( "src/dist/sample-soapui-project.xml" );
    runner.run(); 
}
```

more information [here](http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/integrating-with-junit.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I also added a comment below with my solution.

Comment: @HeLL

If I use this approach, how I will set the properties of the test cases.

Answer (score 4):

Currentyl only SoapUI dependency is needed for @HeLL provided code

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: don't forget to add the soapui repository     <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>soapui</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I fixed it by using:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```