# running groovy script inside a soapUi project using java code

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I have a SoapUI project which has test steps which start with a groovy script which signs all the remaining test steps. This is working fine if We do it through SoapUI client.

But it is failing when I run this using the Java Code described in the following Stackoverflow answer: [How to run soapUI tests from Java [Resolved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908086/how-to-run-soapui-tests-from-java-resolved).

Groovy script fails to sign all the teststeps , but tests continue to run.

> 10:42:20,100 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [No match found], see
>   error log for details java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
>     at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:497)  at
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.extractErrorLineNumber(GroovyUtils.java:145)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:172)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:235)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:48)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:148)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:43)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:135)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.start(AbstractTestRunner.java:77)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.run(WsdlTestCase.java:640)
>     at Test.main(Test.java:69)
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script1.groovy: 7: unable to resolve class
>   au.gov.mca.uhi.security.util.XMLSigner  @ line 1, column 1.    import
>   au.gov.mca.uhi.security.util.XMLSigner;    ^
>   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class
>   au.gov.mca.uhi.security.util.XMLSigner  @ line 7, column 1.   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1145)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:141)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$10.call(CompilationUnit.java:632)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:523)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
>     at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613)     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625)   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652)   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643)   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:235)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:48)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:148)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:43)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:135)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.start(AbstractTestRunner.java:77)
>     at
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.run(WsdlTestCase.java:640)
>     at Test.main(Test.java:69)

Is there any way we can run a teststep which is a groovy script in a soapUI project with Java code.

My Maven dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jgoodies</groupId>
    <artifactId>looks</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.squirrel-sql.thirdparty-non-maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>com-fifesoft-rsyntaxtextarea</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.eik.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jomc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jomc-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You need to provide the script by editing the question. By the way, it is clear that you are using some classes and current classpath is incorrect.

Comment: Hi,
 Java program is failing at the first line of the groovy script i.e import statement.  
>import au.gov.mca.uhi.security.util.XMLSigner;
I have attached more logs to the question.

Comment: That is what I told, required library needs to be in classpath. Do you got the jar of that class? where did you kept it?

Comment: I am using Maven based project , all the dependencies are coming from Maven repo (smartbear site) And my maven file has attached information in the question. Might be missing the ones for Groovy, I am not sure what to use to make it work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: May be you first make sure it works from `SoapUI` to isolate the issue.

Comment: It does work in soapUI.

Comment: Then check the differences in SOAPUI_HOME between the machines where it is working vs not working.

Comment: Its the same system. SAOP UI project works fine from the client, but not from Java program. Maybe I made a mistake to communicate properly with my question.