# SoapUI maven execution results NoClassDefFoundError: com/jniwrapper/PlatformContext

Tags: java, maven, soap, soapui

I am running SOAP UI test case by Junit and which is Java-Maven Project. When I hit the command `mvn clean test`, getting below error

```
15:49:44,469 ERROR [AbstractTestRunner] Exception during Test Execution
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jniwrapper/PlatformContext
    at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.isJXBrowserDisabled(SoapUI.java:1025)
    at com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.isJXBrowserDisabled(SoapUI.java:1006)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.HttpAuthenticationRequestFilter.filterAbstractHttpRequest(HttpAuthenticationRequestFilter.java:83)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filterRequest(AbstractRequestFilter.java:31)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:179)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:123)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.submitRequest(WsdlSubmit.java:76)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest.submit(WsdlRequest.java:238)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep.run(WsdlTestRequestStep.java:417)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:235)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:48)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:148)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:43)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:135)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.start(AbstractTestRunner.java:77)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.run(WsdlTestCase.java:640)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.run(WsdlTestCase.java:73)
    at learn.TestCaseTwo.testRunnerFive(TestCaseTwo.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

*Below is my pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>net.wu.web</groupId>
<artifactId>bddcucumber</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <skipITTests>false</skipITTests>
    <geb.version>0.10.0</geb.version>
    <selenium.version>2.52.0</selenium.version>
    <groovy.version>2.3.6</groovy.version>
    <spock.version>0.7-groovy-2.0</spock.version>
    <gson.version>2.3.1</gson.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.3.4</httpclient.version>
    <httpcore.version>4.3.2</httpcore.version>
    <surefire.plugin.version>2.12.4</surefire.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>soapUI</id>
        <name>eviware</name>
        <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>eviwarePluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>fife</groupId>
        <artifactId>rsyntaxtextarea</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Reference URL :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908086/how-to-run-soapui-tests-from-java-resolved -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jgoodies</groupId>
        <artifactId>looks</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.squirrel-sql.thirdparty-non-maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>com-fifesoft-rsyntaxtextarea</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.eik.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>


        <!-- Maven Surefire plugin-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <!--<groupId>eviware</groupId>-->
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
            <configuration>

                <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <printReport>true</printReport>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

Below is my test case.

```
public class TestCaseTwo {

    WsdlProjectPro project = new WsdlProjectPro("src\\test\\resources\\SOAP\\Spain_KYC_CS_Sanity-soapui-project.xml");
    TestSuite testSuite;
    TestCase testCase;
    TestRunner testRunner;

    @Test
    public void testRunnerOne(){
        testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("Registration");
        testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Registar a new D Type user");

        testRunner = testCase.run(new PropertiesMap(),false);
        Assert.assertEquals(testRunner.getStatus(), TestRunner.Status.FINISHED);
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to remove this Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jniwrapper/PlatformContext

Comment: Check your classpath and include missing library.

Comment: Hi Rao, Thanks for reply, but can you please explain it in detail with exact steps which I need to follow.

Comment: Durgesh, please check the solution to see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add system argument
 `soapui.jxbrowser.disable` and value as `true`

For example adding in the command-line of `maven`

`mvn clean -Dsoapui.jxbrowser.disable=true`

Comment: Hi Rao, Thanks for reply. I have executed below command:

mvn clean -Dsoapui.jxbrowser.disable=true

Now the exception " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jniwrapper/PlatformContext" is not coming. However the strange
part is that, the test case which are running through SOAP UI Pro are not working via java maven.

Do you have any idea, because now exception is changed, however results are same. Thanks!

Comment: @Durgesh, that was a sample command. Please include your `test` goal as well in your command.

Comment: Hi Rao, Sorry for the confusion, I mean that I have executed the command:  mvn clean test -Dsoapui.jxbrowser.disable=true . But got the result mentioned in above comment.

Comment: @Durgesh, sorry, no idea about it.

Comment: Np. Thanks. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: @Durgesh, I am under impression that the issue mentioned in question is resolved with the above. Appreciate an upvote for the helpful answers and if you think this solves the question, consider accepting as answered.