# Is there any possibility to run soapUI testcases parallel through Java

Tags: java, soapui

I have a SoapUI test suite which has couple of test cases. each test cases multiple test step to accomplished the task. So far i'm running sequentially. I'm wondering is there any way that I can run parallel execution of test cases under a Suite. I'm calling SOAPUI from java to execute test step sequentially. To cut down my runtime planning to implements parallel execution approach.

Comment: SoapUI has the ability to run test cases in parallel. There are several discussions on the SoapUI fora of how this can be done from Java. Since you do now show how you are doing it now, and what you have tried, it is very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don' think, any SOAP library supports parallel execution of test suites. What you can do, is use soap libraries to execute SOAP requests & use java executor service or multithreading to get it parallel execution. Here are couple of examples to call SOAP test cases from java, if you are not aware

[How to run soapUI tests from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22908086/how-to-run-soapui-tests-from-java)